# Update content within a referenced model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

I have a problem that I can't seem to find a proper solution for.

First of all, I'm using the meanjs framework, which mean I use express, nodejs, mongoose and mongodb in the backend!

The problem goes like this: Every time I want create a post, I attach a user to the post as it's creator, this is done by using the Schema.ObjectId type in mongoose.

When I create a post I want to give the user a point. So the flow would be something like this:

> Create post-> post.created-> post.postCreator.points+=1

I wanna implement this logic for more things, such as, if others liked your post, you would also recieve a point. The flow would be something like this for that:

> Like post->post.likes+=1->post.postCreator.points+=1

I want this to be done completely in backend but I'am not sure how I would implement this sort of functionality correctly..

In both the examples the post.postCreator is a Schema.ObjectId type, where it references the correct User document.

If someone could point me in the right direction how this should be implemented I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into adding a post save callback?

Comment: yes I was thinking of using a post save callback, but the problem is I don't know how to access the actual user model properly from a callback in another schema.. Do you have an example how that'd work?

Comment: If you have the ID, you would need to get the User instance, and then update it.

Comment: yes but thats the issue I'm having, HOW do I get the user instance..? I do have the userId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the user id from your Post instance, you would then need to query and update the User. Example:

```
schema.post('save', function(p) {
    UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id': p.userId}, {$inc: {points: 1}},
        function(error, user) {
            // do something else with the user if necessary
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Or: `UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id': p.userId}, {$inc: { points: 1} }, function(err, user)   { // ... });`

Comment: Thanks @user3632710 My knowledge of Mongoose continues to expand.

Comment: how would I get hold of the UserSchema? By doing something like 'var UserSchema = mongoose.model('User')'?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, or use `require` if it's in another module.

Comment: it's in another module, but I'm not sure what I should put in the require, I can't seem to figure it out how it should be formatted..

Comment: Perhaps something like `var UserSchema = require('path/to/module').model('User')` ?

Comment: I'am sorry, for some reason it didn't turn into block code.

I'm still having problems, crashes on `UserSchema.findByIdAndUpdate` with the error message `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Found the problem, everything was alright! I just hadn't loaded the User module correctly. Marking answer as correct!